# how to perform Email Validation and restrict personal email id in c# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check whether email is valid or not .
Then check if it's personal email like gmail, yahoo etc.

I can do that with JavaScript but i want to do it in c#  side

Comment: You can do the same regex from javascript in C#, and just check if a substring like gmail etc exists in the string

Comment: can you elaborate

Comment: What do you consider "personal" mail? Also, I'd recommend to _not_ validate email, but send one. Include some validation code or a validation-link and incorporate that in your sign-up process. Except if your requirement is to explicitly exclude some email formats / domains or only explicitly allow specific ones.

Comment: Personal email id  list "google", "msn", "yahoo", "gmail", "hotmail", "outlook", "mac"

Comment: Use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-7.0

Comment: And what shall happen to those? Do you want to block any "whatevername@{personal mail provider}.{extension}"?

Comment: This may also be of interest to you : [How to verify that strings are in valid email format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-verify-that-strings-are-in-valid-email-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Can use MailAddress`

```
    var trimmedEmail = email.Trim();
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || trimmedEmail.EndsWith(".") )
    return false;

    try {
        var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
        return addr.Address == trimmedEmail;
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
```

OR

`EmailAddressAttribute`

```
var email = new EmailAddressAttribute();
email.IsValid(email);
```

If it is true then check it is personal or not by

```
string[] personalEmail = { "gmail","yahoo" };
string email = "xyz@yahoo.in";
var isPersonal= personalEmail.Any(x => email.Contains(x));
```